# How can I generate a file like this for Bing Heat Map data?

Tags: heatmap, bing, bing-api, bing-maps

I am working on a fairly simple Heat Map application where the longitude and latitude of the points will be stored in a SQL Server database. I have been looking at an example that uses an array of objects as follows (eliminated a lot of data for brevity):

```
/* Sample data to demonstrate Bing Maps Heatmap */
/* http://alastair.wordpress.com */
var CrimeData = [
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.67280, 0.94392),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.62423, 1.29493),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.62187, 1.29080),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.58962, 1.72228),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.69915, 0.24332),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.51161, 0.99350),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.59573, 1.17067),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.94351, 0.49153),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.64585, 1.73145),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.75424, 1.30079),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.63566, 1.27176),
new Microsoft.Maps.Location(52.63882, 1.23121)
];
```

What I want to do is present the user with a list of some sort that displays all the data sets that exist in the database (they each have a name associated with them) and then allow the user to check all or only a select few. I will then need to generate an array like the above to create the heat map. Any ideas on a good approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to achieve is more related to a web developement rather than only related to Bing Maps.
To summarize, you have multiple ways to do this but it really depends on what you are capable to do and what you need in the interface.

**What process/technology?**

First, you need to determine what process you want to follow to display the data and it will set the technology that you will use. The questions that you need to ask yourself are:

- Do you want to be able to change the data sets dynamically without refreshing the whole page?

If yes, it means that you will have to use asynchronous data loading through a dedicated web service in order to avoid loading all the information at the initial load of the page.

- Do you have lots of data to load?

If so, it might comfort you with asynchronous loading to avoid loading all data.
If not loading every elements in multiple arrays might be the simplest solution.

**Implementation**

So now, you want to create a web service to load the data asynchronously, you can take a look at the following websites :

- http://www.asp.net/get-started
- http://www.stefanprodan.com/2011/04/async-operations-with-jquery-ajax-and-asp-net-mvc/

There might be interesting other website, you will be able to find them. If needed, add comment and I'm sure the community will help you.

If you want to generate the data directly in the script, it could be simple as you can compose the JavaScript directly in your dynamically created HTML page (in your ASP.Net markup code or whatever technology you're using).

Comment: Client has changed their needs. Is there a way to assign a weight to each set of long and lat values?

Comment: You will have to update Alastair's algorithm but it could be done so the heat map reflect your own logic

Comment: Can you tell me about Microsoft.Maps.Location.prototype.multiplier? Am I able to add that to EACH location that I add to the map? For instance, can I assign a number to a location and then add up all those numbers for a given long/lat and attach that to the map?

Comment: Also, how does colourgradient work? I want to assign one color per business segment so that I can see them on the map. In Power View this is possible as I have an example from the client, but they don't know how that was done and Power View doesn't make it obvious.